# Pass javascript variable to php with ajax , Nothing result?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**MY js page :**

```
$m = 77;    
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
xhr.open("POST", "try.php", true);    
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
xhr.send("m=" + escape(m));
```

**php page :**

```
$var = $_POST['m'];    
echo $var;
```

When I call php page nothing happens! can you help me?

Comment: change `$m = 77;` to `m = 77;`

Comment: change to var m = 77;

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work !!

Answer (score 2):

**Just you need to change variable m to get expected output**

```
    m = 77; // here what i have changed from $m to m

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "try.php", true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.send("m=" + escape(m));
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work again !! when i load php file i see nothing and the php variable is null

Comment: Ok, so can you show me the whole code, let me make help to you.

Comment: In fact i have two file 1st is try.php  and 2nd is try.js (and i posted both of them)                                                          
and the problem is that php will interpret before js file this is why i have nothing as result, so how can do that please , thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, but how do i pass a variable js to a variable php without submit button? if fact i made a casino game with js and i made some calculation (the user put a depature number) this number will decrease, untill it will be 0, int this case i need to send a result to a php variable without click on button (automaticly when depature =0) to store it into my msql table,

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

## Variable names

At the top of your code you create a variable called `$m` but later you try to read `m`.

This will throw a ReferenceError which you would have spotted if you had looked at the Console in your browser's Developer Tools

## You never look at the response

Once you fix that error, your code will make the request … but you don't do anything with the response.

You should add a load event listener for that.

```
function alert_response() {
    alert(this.responseText);
}

xhr.addEventListener("load", alert_response);
```

## Asides

- `escape` is *deprecated* because it doesn't work properly. Use `encodeURIComponent` instead.
- PHP sticks a `text/html` content-type on the response by default, by echoing out user input without modification or filtering, you are vulnerable to XSS attacks. Take steps to defend yourself.

Comment: But i have a problem with this function, in fact when i load my php page it result an alert js and it display whole my text js and html !!

Comment: and here in order of your explanations i will store a php variable into js variable but i want the opposite !

Comment: @JAVAJAVA — The code was provided as a demonstration of how to access the response. It is up to you to decide what to do with it. If you just want to show a whole new page, then **don't use Ajax**! Just use a regular form submission. If you don't want the PHP to send back a big pile of HTML, then change the PHP so it doesn't do that (the code you put in the question, by itself, won't do that anyway).

Comment: @JAVAJAVA — Your code is showing an attempt to send a JS variable to PHP. The section of this answer headed "Variable names" explains how to fix the problems with it. To pass data from PHP to JS … you have to do what the section titled "You never look at the response" does … just change what you do with the data using my example of `alert()` as a basis for it.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i pass a variable js to a variable php without submit button? if fact i made a casino game with js and i made some calculation (the user put a depature number) this number will decrease, untill it will be 0, int this case i need to send a result to a php variable without click on button (automaticly when depature =0)  to store it into my msql table,

Comment: @JAVAJAVA — There's nothing in the code you have already that requires a submit button to trigger it.

Comment: yes i don't need i button, i want just recover a variable from js into php how can i do that ?

Comment: It display anything !

Comment: @JAVAJAVA — You said you wanted the script to insert data into a database and nothing else. That means it shouln't display anything! If you want it to display something, then see this answer!

Comment: yes but if i can't display it , i can never store it , i want to try to display it with php variable if it work then i can store it

Comment: The problem is that php interpreted before js, is there any possibility to interprate js before php?

Comment: @JAVAJAVA — PHP is interpreted between the request being made and the response being sent. The entire point of Ajax is to **send a new request** (without leaving the page). The response (which happens after the PHP has run) triggers the `load` event that the section of this answer titled "You never look at the response" demonstrates.

Comment: thanks, but i still have problems, i still can't recover the result from js into php!! :(

Comment: @JAVAJAVA — Your existing code already does that. What makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: i really don't know, when i load php file it dosen't display anything with 'echo'

Comment: note i have just this two file, i want to test if it works i can do the same for my project

Comment: @JAVAJAVA — Why should it display anything? Your JavaScript is ignoring the response. See the part of this answer titled "You never look at the response" if you want to look at what PHP is sending back.